# O que acontece com a preposição nas frases em que o objeto indireto é um advérbio?

Tags: preposições, advérbios, regência-verbal

Considere, por gentileza, essas frases:

1. Ele vai lá?
2. Cheguei aqui ontem.
3. Você deve chegar ali.

Nelas, a regência do verbo requer preposição. Contudo, no caso o objeto indireto é um advérbio e essas frases só são perfeitamente naturais se a preposição *a* não for usada. Pelo contrário, forçar a preposição as faz extremamente esquisitas (*Ele vai a lá?*, *Cheguei a aqui ontem*, ...).

Seria isso alguma exceção à regra? Procurei em vários sítios mas não encontrei nada, e nenhum me pareceu confiável o suficiente a bem da verdade, sendo o melhorzinho [este aqui](http://www.nilc.icmc.usp.br/nilc/minigramatica/mini/objetoindireto.htm), mas onde nada consta.

Por outro lado,

4. Pulei dali pra cá.

também parece correta, e tirar a preposição (*Pulei ali pra cá*) fica seguramente incorreto, o que me deixa ainda mais confuso.

Comment: Se pesquisares as palavras no dicionários, verás que também tem significado de "para"; ex.: "[cá] 1. Aqui; neste lugar; nesta terra; para aqui.". Como podem significar "este/esse/aquele lugar", não vejo problema em "vem para cá" ou "ele foi para ali". Duvido que "pulei ali para cá" esteja errado, vê "ali eu pulei para cá", mesmo que não faça muito sentido.

Comment: @Schilive Tem toda a razão, falhei em não consultar o dicionário, eu pensei que era alguma exceção gramatical e fiquei procurando algo nesse sentido. Seu último comentário também me parece apropriado, "pulei ali para cá" não é errado, apenas dá outro sentido. Gostaria de escrever uma resposta? Se não, eu a escreverei para que a pergunta não fique aberta.

Comment: Você tem certeza de que seus exemplos são "objetos indiretos"?  Então qual seria a sua definição de "adjunto adverbial"?

Comment: @Centaurus Agora você me pegou. De fato, *chegar* e *ir* podem ser transitivos ou intransitivos. Se o adjunto é o caso aqui, não sei dizer, a distinção parece ser bem sutil na maioria dos casos.